# QAudioProbe progress bar connection

Tags: c++, qt, qt-creator

I'm sorry if stupid question, but I am totally begginer in C++ an in QT creator and it's my first post here. I tried to search answer for my issue but can't find.

I just want to understand how QAudioProbe class works. And I try to monitor of my QAudioRecorder and send it to progress bar to see it jumping when I'm recording something.

I tried that code from http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qaudioprobe.html#details :

```
probka = new QAudioProbe;
connect(probka, SIGNAL(audioBufferProbed(QAudioBuffer)), this, 
                           SLOT(processBuffer(QAudioBuffer)));

probka->setSource(audioRecorder);
```

But I don't know what to do next? I tried something like that:

```
connect(probka, SIGNAL(audioBufferProbed(QAudioBuffer)), ui->progressBar, SLOT(setValue(int)));
```

but it doesn't work. Actually I've tried a lot of coding, I've been trying to solve my issue for two days. I also launched example project of QAudioRecorder and tried to analyze it, I even think I understand it a little bit, but still can't make that stupid connection of QAudioProbe with my progress bar.

And I also have one question in little bit different topic. How to find the QT built in definitions of some functions. For example when I click right button on some function and select "Follow symbol under cursor" it goes to the declaration of function, but then I want to see what that function exactly does, how to find that? I tried "Switch header/source F4" but it works only for my own functions, but not with QT built in classes.

For any help thanks in advance, and sorry for my English. :)

Comment: I also dream about how to get level of recorded signal by using QAudioProbe, and also is it possible to to get recorded audio frequency to display musical value of tone frequency? I can imagine how to do that for sine wave, but for example human voice is quite different that sine wave and has a lot of harmonic tones, so how to get that main tone frequecy? Can anyone help? I know the JUCE application provides a lot of musical tools but I need to do it in QT creator. That's the case :)

Comment: Do you want to display the size of the buffer in the progress bar ?, If so, the progress bar is a relative measure since it measures a percentage, in your case, regarding what measure you want to compare the size of the buffer?

Comment: I want to monitor the peak level of recording sound, something like in most of audio consoles. Something like on that video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JYqQCP0yo2o

Comment: Even in the official documentation of QAudioProbe, there is sentence like that: "Now we can do things like calculating levels or performing an FFT". But How to do that?

Comment: OK, I found the solution. It was much simpler than I thought. You don't need to use "connect" function. You can directly assign level change to the progres bar setValue(levelChange)